# Angular2+: Toggling element in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, angular

I have multiple div's with toggling `<i>` elements.  However, in my attempt, when I click on one div's `<i>`(i.e. *fa-bookmark*), it toggles all of the other div's corresponding `<i>`.

What I want is to be able to toggle the `<i>` in each individual div and not affect the other div's.

My HTML:

```
   <div class="crit-desc crit-item-flags order-item-flags">
        <i class="fal fa-bookmark" (click)="flagActive('bookmark')" [ngClass]="items['bookmark'].flagStatus ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"></i>
        <i class="fal fa-alarm-clock" (click)="flagActive('alarmClock')" [ngClass]="items['alarmClock'].flagStatus ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"></i>
    </div>
/*Repeat above HTML*/
    <div class="crit-desc crit-item-flags order-item-flags">
        <i class="fal fa-bookmark" (click)="flagActive('bookmark')" [ngClass]="items['bookmark'].flagStatus ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"></i>
        <i class="fal fa-alarm-clock" (click)="flagActive('alarmClock')" [ngClass]="items['alarmClock'].flagStatus ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"></i>
    </div>
```

My TS:

```
export class FlagsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  items = {
    'flag': { flagStatus: false },
    'bookmark': { flagStatus: false },
    'alarmClock': { flagStatus: false }
  };
  flagActive(item) {
    console.log(this.items[item]);
    this.items[item].flagStatus = !this.items[item].flagStatus;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you check the same item in every divs so this is how it should be work. You have one item object instead of an array of items.

Answer (score 0):

you can use in one div

```
[hidden]="flag"
```

and in other div

```
[hidden]="!flag"
```

and make a click event

```
 <i class="fal fa-bookmark" (click)="flagActive()"></i>
```

and your function look like

```
function flagActive(){
 this.flag = !this.flag
}
```

Comment: THis wouldn't work because it would still affect the other div's.  I want the toggle to only affect the div it's being toggled in.

Answer (score 0):

Use Directive if you want to repeat Div

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appToggle]',
  exportAs:'appToggle'
})
export class ToggleDirective {
  toggle:boolean=false;
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick(){
     this.toggle=!this.toggle;
  }

}
```

Then use Different template variable for different div

```
<div class="crit-desc crit-item-flags order-item-flags">
        <i class="fa fa-bookmark" 
        appToggle
        #bookmark="appToggle"       
         [ngClass]="bookmark.toggle === true ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"          
        appToggle
        #alarm="appToggle"      
         [ngClass]="alarm.toggle === true ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"       
        ></i>
    </div>

    {{bookmark | json}}
    {{alarm | json}}

/*Repeat above HTML*/
    <div class="crit-desc crit-item-flags order-item-flags">
        <i class="fa fa-bookmark" 
        appToggle
        #bookmark1="appToggle"         
         [ngClass]="bookmark1.toggle === true ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"></i>  
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"           
        appToggle
        #alarm1="appToggle"       
         [ngClass]="alarm1.toggle === true ? 'flagActive' : 'flagNotActive'"         
        ></i>
    </div>

    {{bookmark1 | json}}
    {{alarm1 | json}}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoveflow-toggle-div